# .Net core2 CORS - How SetIsOriginAllowed works?

Tags: asp.net-core, cors

Want to allow my API to be accessed from different sites. For this had:

```
services
    .AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(PolicyName, builder =>
        {
            builder
                .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                .WithOrigins(
                    "http://*.my-api.com",
                    "http://*.my-api.service"
                )
...
```

This doesn't seem to allow httpS or when I specify the port in the request.

Ex.:
https://www.my-api.com:3000

Thought could replace the WithOrigins with SetIsOriginAllowed()

```
services
    .AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(PolicyName, builder =>
        {
            builder
                .SetIsOriginAllowed(IsOriginAllowed)
```

where IsOriginAllowed function is defined as:

```
private static bool IsOriginAllowed(string host)
{
    var corsOriginAllowed = new[] { "my-api.com", "my-api.service" };

    return corsOriginAllowed.Any(origin =>
        Regex.IsMatch(host, $@"^http(s)?://.*{origin}(:[0-9]+)?$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
}
```

but this doesn't work at all, even the regular expression is returning true when I want.

Does anyone know why this doesn't work and can show me the right way to allow httpS (besides duplicating all the domains in WithOrigins() with httpS and different ports.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SetIsOriginAllowed() does work. Was testing with Postman and as was told, Postman doesn't care about headers returned from the server. It's the browser who enforces the Cors headers.

To test properly created a little html page under a test site with below javascript

```html
<html>
    <script>
        fetch('http://test.com:5000/v2/campaign/hallo3').then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        }).then(function(j) {            
         alert(JSON.stringify(j));
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

when domain is NOT included in the Cors allowed list browser doesn't display the returned values from API

[image: Domain not allowed]

After adding test domain to allowed domains list browser display the data and get the content Cors headers

[image]

Another problem was that with just the SetIsOriginAllowed() server was not sending the 'Vary' header. Had to set both:

```
.SetIsOriginAllowed(IsOriginAllowed)
.WithOrigins(corsOriginAllowed)
```

Comment: I see you use the corsOriginAllowed as a variable defined in the code. Can we use the "AllowedHosts" configuration from appsettings.json? what is the use of this configuration "allowedHosts". i looked up on the internet around and didnt get one clear answer or explanation of its purpose. Can you help me on that @Riga

Answer (score 3):

**23/12/2022**

For anyone struggling with this in **NET CORE 7** try this on Program.cs:

1. Add the variable:

   ```
   ...
   var MyHosts = "myHosts";
   var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
   ...
   ```
2. Add the new CORS policy:

   ```
   if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
   {
   ///Add a CORS policy to allow certain hosts
   builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
   {
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyHosts,
                      policy =>
                      {  
                        policy.AllowAnyOrigin().WithOrigins("http://localhost:59028").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
                      });
   ```

   });
   }

U have to add the AllowAnyHeader and AllowAnyMethod or u'll get another pre-flight error.

3. Don't forget to add the new policy below:

   ```
    app.UseCors(MyHosts);
   ```